# TypeIt JQuery Plugin: How do you type one line [then wait] and type the 2nd line (all in H1 tags)

Tags: jquery, html

Please be nice I am not a coder :)

This is what i want to achieve:

I want to ask a question using the TypeIt JQuery Plugin.
WAIT.
Then display the answer

Making sure all the text in is H1 tags.

(from what ive read you cant use the pause setting while defining the string)  <-- I dunno *shrug*

---

Im trying to do this:

Need a Digital Copywriter? [WAIT...]

Compelling. Customised Content. Refreshed Weekly.

We Schedule All Copy For You - Easy! [BOLD] Order Now

---

This is my code:
(ive pasted in code from typeit experimenting with having a q and a but thats not the solution it seems.) *Ive been fiddling with this code so I dunno where i am at*

```
<h1 id="Question1">Need a Digital Copywriter? Compelling. Customised 
Content. Refreshed Weekly. We Schedule All Copy For You - Easy! Order 
Now.</h1>
<script 
src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.typeit/4.4.0/typeit.min.js">
</script>
<script>// <![CDATA[
$('#Question1').typeIt({ speed: 180, autoStart: false, lifelike: 
true})
// ]]></script>
<p id="example4">&nbsp;</p>
<script>// <![CDATA[
$('#').typeIt({ speed: 200, autoStart: false, lifelike: 
true}).tiType('Need a Digital Copywriter?') .tiPause(500) 
.tiSettings({speed: 700}) .tiType('...') .tiPause(750) 
.tiSettings({speed: 50}) .tiType('Compelling.') .tiBreak() 
.tiPause(750) .tiType(' Customised Content.') .tiSettings({speed: 
700}) .tiType('...') .tiPause(750) .tiSettings({speed: 50}) 
.tiType('Refreshed Weekly. We Schedule All Copy For You - 
<strong>Easy! Order Now</strong>');
// ]]></script>
```

preview : https://preview.hs-sites.com/_hcms/preview/template/multi?is_buffered_template_layout=true&portalId=3304123&style_id=hubspot-default-basic&tc_deviceCategory=desktop&template_layout_id=5211941467

Im lost and need help.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this: [Working Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8nbkcaru/1/)

This will first type first paragraph and then continue on second paragraph.

HTML:

```
<h1 id="Question1">Need a Digital Copywriter? Compelling. Customised 
Content. Refreshed Weekly. We Schedule All Copy For You - Easy! Order 
Now.</h1>
<p id="example4">&nbsp;</p>
```

jQuery:

```
$('#Question1').typeIt({ speed: 180, autoStart: false, lifelike: true,callback:secondParagraph});

function secondParagraph(){
    $('#example4').typeIt({ speed: 200, autoStart: false, lifelike: true}).tiType('Need a Digital Copywriter?') .tiPause(500).tiSettings({speed: 700}).tiType('...').tiPause(750).tiSettings({speed: 50}).tiType('Compelling.').tiBreak().tiPause(750).tiType(' Customised Content.').tiSettings({speed: 
700}) .tiType('...').tiPause(750).tiSettings({speed: 50}).tiType('Refreshed Weekly. We Schedule All Copy For You - <strong>Easy! Order Now</strong>');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is a pity that in your second code block you have to put the text again, which is already present in your HTML.

You could drive some of the delays within the HTML, by using:

- `<br>`: this will put the text that follows on a next line, and the corresponding delay can be influenced with the `breakDelay` option in `typeIt`
- repeated spaces: in HTML repeated spaces are compressed into one space, unless you have CSS applied that will override this behaviour (e.g. this is the case with the `pre` HTML tag). But for `typeIt` all these spaces are part of the text, and so it spends time on each of them without any visual effect. This comes down to creating a pause
- To have bold text in `h1` texts, you'll have to change the default setting for `h1` tags, since by default they are already in bold. You can use CSS styling to make `h1` tag render as not-bold, and then use `strong` tags in your HTML for the part you want in bold.

Here is an example. Note that the `&nbsp;` are not required, but I added them so you can see there are many repeated spaces preceding it.

```js
$('#Question1').typeIt({ 
    speed: 100,
    autoStart: false, 
    lifelike: true,
    breakDelay: 3000
});
```

```css
h1 { font-weight: normal; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/typeit/4.4.0/typeit.min.js"></script>

<h1 id="Question1">Need a Digital Copywriter?   .   .   .   <br>
Compelling.                                  &nbsp;
Customised Content.                              &nbsp;
Refreshed Weekly.    .    .    .                     &nbsp;
We Schedule All Copy For You - Easy!<span>                             </span>
<strong>Order Now.</strong></h1>
```

Obviously you cannot do everything with just the HTML. Changing speeds that do not involve spaces would be harder to mimic (although here are white space characters that do not take up any space).